# iptables blocks port-forwarded requests to port 80

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, lets-encrypt

My iptables rules are:

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.2.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.2.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.2.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.2.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.2.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 4567 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -i tun0 -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

I want to renew a TLS certificates using Let's Encrypt and for that I need port 80 to be open, so I forwarded it in my router.

However, when checking the logs (I temporarily added a rule with `j LOG` for the `INPUT` chain), I can see that port 80 is being hit with the remote address as source IP (which, of course, is outside my local network) and according to my `iptables` rules, only `192.168.2.0/24` can access my webserver.

How do I do this? Do I need to change my firewall rules everytime I want to update my TLS certificate?

I am a little surprised, as well, because I thought that using NAT, the source IP    would be my router's IP and not the actual remote IP making the request...

Comment: What you are seeing is normal and expected. If you saw the source IP as your router, it would be broken.

Comment: What Michael said. You're using DNAT (destination NAT), not SNAT (source NAT). Alternatively, if the router was actively proxying the requests, then you would see the router's own IP.Configure your webserver to only allow access to /.well-known/ to IP addresses outside your local network.